# Is Nothing issue vba

Tags: vba

Look my code below:

```
Sub AdvencedFilterNew()
'
' AdvencedFilterNew Macro
'

    Dim WsOutput As Worksheet
    Dim WsMain As Worksheet
    Dim wsScenarios As Worksheet
    Dim ScenarioIDrow As Long
    Dim ScenarioIDColumn As Long
    Dim rgn As Range
    Dim p As String
    Dim q As String
    Dim f As Range

    Set WsOutput = Worksheets("Output")
    Set WsMain = Worksheets("Main Menu")
    Set wsScenarios = Worksheets("Scenarios.New")

    WsOutput.Activate
    Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    WsMain.Activate
    Range("E15").Select
    Range("E17:Q350").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    Range("E14:Q15"), Unique:=False


    ScenarioIDrow = WsOutput.Cells.Find("Scenario ID").Row
    ScenarioIDColumn = WsOutput.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    p = wsScenarios.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, 2).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    q = wsScenarios.Cells(ScenarioIDrow, ScenarioIDColumn).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)


    WsOutput.Activate
    WsOutput.Range(p, q).Select
    Set f = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets("Main Menu").Range("E15").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    For Each rgn In Selection

    If rgn = f Then

    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    ElseIf f Is Nothing Then
    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Else
    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If

    Next rgn

    WsMain.Activate
    WsMain.Range("E15").Select
```

So, it works fine but when my range(e15) = f is nothing(blanK) an error pops up, even it does what I want. "Error 91. Object or variable or With block variable not set. Anyone knows why? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify on which line the program crashes. I assume it's:

```
If rgn = f Then
```

The `=` operator compares two variables for equality. If the left and/or right side is an object, the object's content is compared for equality. So the variable is dereference. That won't work for *Nothing* as it references nothing.

What you want instead is compare for identity, i.e. check if two object variables reference the same object. For that purpose, Visual Basic and VBA have the `IS` operator.

So to fix it, you either change the line to:

```
If rgn = f Then
```

Or you simply rearrange the order of the statements to:

```
If f Is Nothing Then
    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
ElseIf rgn = f Then
    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    rgn.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End If
```